# How to insert record to sharepoint multi choice field via CSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I am trying to insert a Multichoice (checkbox) field to sharepoint via the SP namespace in javascript.

Updatnig single choice is simple.

For Multichoice I have tried:

```
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
newListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
var checked = $('input[name=' + field.internalName + 'group]:checked');
var value = new Array();
checked.each(function (i, item) {
   value.push(item.getAttribute('value'));
})
newListItem.set_item(field.internalName, value);

newListItem.update();
context.load(newListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(onInsertSucceeded, onInsertFailed);
```

so value with set_item it is trying to upload a array, I have also tried making it a string separating values with a ';'
Both options through an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var item;
function insertItem()
{
   var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
   newListItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
   var checked = $('input[name=' + field.internalName + 'group]:checked');

   // loop through the choices and concat with ','
   newListItem.set_item(field.internalName, 'Choice1, Choice 2');
   newListItem.update();

   context.executeQueryAsync(onInsertSucceeded, onInsertFailed);

}
function onInsertSucceeded() {
        alert("Item updated");
    }
function onInsertFailed() {
        alert('Failure!');
    }
```

Comment: Just curious @michael, but how did this answer help you? Using ',' should work just as fine as Array. I think the real problem is getting values from `checked`, which is not shown at all here

Comment: Not sure why the questioner liked my answer.. I prefer your's too..

Answer (score 6):

I just did a simple test, and this code works just fine:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var item = context.get_web().get_lists()
  .getByTitle('Test')
  .addItem(new SP.ListItemCreationInformation());
item.set_item('MyField', ['Hello', 'World']);
item.update();
context.executeQueryAsync();
```

And this is quite identical to your code, so that makes me wonder if your variable `value` contains correct data. Could you set a breakpoint or simply `console.log` the variable after your loop?

One way to get the text of the checkboxes is to go for the labels, if you have them, like this:

```
var values = $('input:checked').map(function(){ 
  return $(this).next('label').text(); 
}).toArray();
```

Comment: @erikb I have same issue.. but your approach not working in SP2016 on premise